# How to improve performance of data saving in Entity Framwork using db.savechange() funcation in recursive function of C# or other option available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am saving and updating records by using a recursive function but it's using too much time - around 2 minutes for saving records. I am using Entity Framework for database access.

Guideline best practice for Entity Framework is most welcome

There is N level of child so we don't know how many child we have so 
I have tried call `db.savechange()` after completion of recursive but no luck for this.

I have this type code skeleton (it's not original, I have just added structure).

```
public void parentFunction(List<DataListforupdate> dataListforupdates, string defaultvalue, Guid perentguid)
{
    if (dataListforupdates != null && dataListforupdates.Count() >)
    {
        foreach (var model in dataListforupdates)
        {
            // manipulate data for save
            saveDateInDB(model.value, model.value, model.value, model.value);

            if (model.child.count() > 0)
            {
                ChildFunction(model.child.dataListforupdates, defaultvalue, perentguid)
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var getAllDataForupdate = db.tbl.where(x => x.gID = perentguid).toList();

        foreach (var model in getAllDataForupdate)
        {
            // manipulate data for save
            saveDateInDB(defaultvalue, model.value, model.value, model.value);

            if (model.child.count() > 0)
            {
                ChildFunction(model.child.dataListforupdates, defaultvalue, perentguid)
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ChildFunction(List<DataListforupdate> dataListforupdates, string defaultvalue, Guid perentguid)
{
    // update model date if its not null
    if (dataListforupdates != null && dataListforupdates.Count() >)
    {
        foreach (var model in dataListforupdates)
        {
            // manipulate data for save
            saveDateInDB(model.value, model.value, model.value, model.value);

            if (model.child.count() > 0)
            {
                ChildFunction(model.child.dataListforupdates, defaultvalue, perentguid)
            }
        }
    }
    // if model date is null then update all record with default value 
    else
    {
        var getAllDataForupdate = db.tbl.where(x => x.gID = perentguid).toList();

        foreach (var model in getAllDataForupdate)
        {
            // manipulate data for save
            saveDateInDB(defaultvalue, model.value, model.value, model.value);

            if (model.child.count() > 0)
            {
                ChildFunction(model.child.dataListforupdates, defaultvalue, perentguid)
            }
        }
    }
}

public void saveDateInDB(string value1, string value2, string value3, string value4)
{
    var getAddedData = db.DataFromTable.where(x => x.id = value1).FirstOrDefault()

    if (getAddedData != null)
    {
        // update date using db.savechanges()
    }
    else
    {
        // Add date using db.savechanges()
    }
}
```

is it speed issue because of i am calling db for get list in each recursive?

Comment: Why cant you get all your records together, and save them all at once?

Comment: there is N level of child so we don't know how many child we have

Comment: if you cant change anything, then you can make it faster

Comment: there are thousand of data in parent table and child table so its take time to save data

Comment: **Typo** alert. it's a **default** - not a "defult" .....

Comment: @ marc_s thanks a lot

Comment: I think your best bet is to, as you've said you tried, only call savechanges once at the end but when you say no luck, do you mean, it didn't save it at all or didn't improve speed?

Comment: i mean no luck means no significant improvement in speed

Comment: I suggest to try bulk insert based on a comparison its the most efficient way to insert big number of records.https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert see the comparison  http://mohdalghanem.blogspot.com/2015/05/improve-data-insertion-performance-in.html

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried call db.savechange() after completion of recursive but
>   no luck for this.

SavingChanges() at once suppose to improve application performance instead of doing savechanges for every child. It does not make sense. On recursive you should only change the state of the entity to modified. Also you can disable change tracking.

```
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Plus you should get all datas from database at once. On recursive you should not go to database. It's not a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently suffers from 3 performances issue:

- Detect Changes caused by multiple add/attach
- Database round-trip to check if data exists
- Database round-trip to save the data

#### Detect Changes caused by multiple add/attach

More entities you have in your context, slower the detect change method become: https://entityframework.net/why-detect-changes-slow

For example, at 10,000 entities, it might take longer than 20ms to add a single entity in the Change Tracker when initially it was taking 0ms.

Possible solution:

- Create a `List<AddedData>` that you will pass in your recursive method. Once your parent function has completed adding all recursive entity to the list. Use `AddRange` to add them all in your context (The AddRange only perform a DetectChanges once)
- Disable temporarily the detect changes `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` and re-enable/perform it manually inside the parent function once all recursive entity has been added.

#### Database round-trip to check if data exists

You make a database round-trip for every entity to check if it exists in the database.

So if you want to save 10,000 entities, 10,000 database roundtrip is performed which you need to find a way to reduce.

Possible solution:

- You could load all ids in a dictionary instead (only id, not the whole entity). that solution works great but becomes less appealing as your table growth. So it's not recommended for a very large table.
- If you successfully make a list instead to save later, you could verify using a select id + contains instead to check multiple entities at once, it will allow reducing the number of database round-trip (splitting them into multiple batches might be required if you have too much entity to save)
- If you successfully make a list instead to save later, use BulkMerge from [EF Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/) (will talk later of this solution)

#### Database round-trip to save the data

You make a database round-trip for every entity to save.

So if you want to save 10,000 entities, 10,000 database roundtrip is performed which you need to find a way to reduce.

Possible solution:

- Using a library such as [EF Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/) that provides bulk functionalities such as Bulk Merge.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but extends to your `DbContext` with bulk extension methods :

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Batch SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

In your case, you are looking for `Bulk Merge` that will update existing entities and insert not matching one.

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkMerge(customers);

// Easy to customize
context.BulkMerge(invoices, options => options.IncludeGraph = true);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind solution, but i cant effort your library because i am single no profit developer

Comment: No problem, you can still improve the #1 and #2 without our library. You can indefinitely use our library for free as well if you download the latest version at the beginning of every month if your project can allow such a thing.